# a really complicated loop. Can someone help me?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I must execute a command several times changing from time to time the two files of input. I think that i have to run a loop, probably a "for" but I don't know how. 
The command is the following:

```
"....." -ps -i xxxx_X.pdb -gl Pocket_nnn_xxxx_X.pdb -o output.txt
```

The two input files are those after the `-i` and `-gl` options and they are related to each other, in the sense that to an input file for the `-i` option correspond N files for the `-gl` option (they could be 1 as 10): The correlation is given by the name. For example, the first file could be the following: `1crt_A.pdb` and the second `Pocket_001_1crt_A.pdb` ... at the same time there could be another file `Pocket_002_1crt_a.pdb`. 
In addition to iterating the command for each file, the problem is also that they are all under the same directory but each is within a subdirectory whose name is the name of the input `-i` file.
For example we will have a directory called `ALL` inside which there will be a subdirectory `1crt.A` inside here there will be several files including the two input files described above.
Furthermore, each command generates an output file like this:

```
Input PDB-File:         1crt_A.pdb
Pocket File:            Pocket_001_1crt_A.pdb
eeeeee:                 405.0  
wwwwwwwwwwwww:          71.7    (17.7%)
rrrrrrrrrrrrr:          221.9   (54.8%)
tttttttttttttttt:       206.7   (51.0%)
yyyyyyyyyyyyyy:         84.4    (20.8%)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:     92.0    (22.7%)
BBBBBBBBBBBBB:          536.6  
cgdfeehhhhh:            458
tyrudioh:               78
serfgg:                 2        15
eeeeeeeeeeee:           5        5
```

I would like to extract, for each generated file output, the line 2 column 2 (`Pocket_001_1crt_A.pdb`) copy it to a new text file (`SUMMARY_ALL.txt`) and on the same line report the information present on lines 8 (`AAAAA`) and 9 (`BBBBB`) columns 2 and 3.
The new text file should look like this:

```
                        AAAAAA   AAAAA(%)   BBBBBB
Pocket_001_1crt_A.pdb   92.0     (22.7%)     536.6
```

This last operation must be done for all the generated ouput files and copy the parts of interest on the same file (`SUMMARY_ALL.txt`).

**Example**

These are typical files:

The main directory: `home/Desktop/Work` in the directory `work` there are a lot of directories and the name of these directories is `XXXX_X` (for example: `2ert_A`, `7rtf_3`, `9yhj_B`....). In each directory there is a file called `XXXX_X.pdb` and one or more files called `Pocket_nnn_XXXX_X.pdb`.

For examples: 
- in `home/Desktop/Work/2ert_A` there are `2ert_A.pdb` and `Pocket_001_2ert_A.pdb`
- in `home/Desktop/Work/7rtf_3` there are `7rtf_3.pdb`, `Pocket_001_7rtf_3.pdb`, `Pocket_002_7rtf_3.pdb` and `Pocket_003_7rtf_3.pdb`

The same in all the directories `XXXX_X`

For each directory `XXXX_X` I want use this command:

```
'....' -ps -i xxxx_X.pdb -gl Pocket_nnn_xxxx_X.pdb -o Pocket_nnn_xxxx_X_OUTPUT.txt
```

in which the file input -i (`XXXX_X.pdb`) is always the same while the file -gl (`Pocket_nnn_XXXX_X.pdb`) change (this only if there are more file in the directory `XXXX_X` called `Pocket_nnn_XXXX_X.pdb`, otherwise the command line should only be applied once).

Whenever the command line is applied, and therefore for each `Pocket_nnn_XXXX_X.pdb` file it will be genereted a file output (`Pocket_nnn_xxxx_X_OUTPUT.txt`) like this:

```
Input PDB-File:         XXXX_X.pdb
Pocket File:            Pocket_nnn_XXXX_X.pdb
eeeeee:                 405.0  
wwwwwwwwwwwww:          71.7    (17.7%)
rrrrrrrrrrrrr:          221.9   (54.8%)
tttttttttttttttt:       206.7   (51.0%)
yyyyyyyyyyyyyy:         84.4    (20.8%)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:     92.0    (22.7%)
BBBBBBBBBBBBB:          536.6  
cgdfeehhhhh:            458
tyrudioh:               78
serfgg:                 2        15
eeeeeeeeeeee:           5        5
```

My goal is to obtain at the end a single text file (`SUMMARY_ALL.txt`) containing all the lines relating to the `AAAAAAA` info of each `Pocket_nnn_xxxx_X_OUTPUT.txt` file.

For example, if I have only the two directory `2ert_A`, `7rtf_3` the work is this:

- in `home/Desktop/Work/2ert_A` there are `2ert_A.pdb` and `Pocket_001_2ert_A.pdb`

The command line:

```
'....' -ps -i 2ert_A.pdb -gl Pocket_001_2ert_A.pdb -o Pocket_001_2ert_A_OUTPUT.txt
```

The `Pocket_001_2ert_A_OUTPUT.txt` file:

```
Input PDB-File:         2ert_A.pdb
Pocket File:            Pocket_001_2ert_A.pdb
eeeeee:                 405.0  
wwwwwwwwwwwww:          71.7    (17.7%)
rrrrrrrrrrrrr:          221.9   (54.8%)
tttttttttttttttt:       206.7   (51.0%)
yyyyyyyyyyyyyy:         84.4    (20.8%)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:     92.0    (22.7%)
BBBBBBBBBBBBB:          536.6  
cgdfeehhhhh:            458
tyrudioh:               78
serfgg:                 2        15
eeeeeeeeeeee:           5        5
```

- in `home/Desktop/Work/7rtf_3` there are `7rtf_3.pdb`, `Pocket_001_7rtf_3.pdb`, `Pocket_002_7rtf_3.pdb` and `Pocket_003_7rtf_3.pdb`

The command line:

```
'....' -ps -i 7rtf_3.pdb -gl Pocket_001_7rtf_3.pdb -o Pocket_001_7rtf_3_OUTPUT.txt
```

The `Pocket_001_2ert_A_OUTPUT.txt` file:

```
Input PDB-File:         7rtf_3.pdb
Pocket File:            Pocket_001_7rtf_3.pdb
eeeeee:                 405.0  
wwwwwwwwwwwww:          71.7    (17.7%)
rrrrrrrrrrrrr:          221.9   (54.8%)
tttttttttttttttt:       206.7   (51.0%)
yyyyyyyyyyyyyy:         84.4    (20.8%)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:     80.0   (10.7%)
BBBBBBBBBBBBB:          536.6  
cgdfeehhhhh:            458
tyrudioh:               78
serfgg:                 2        15
eeeeeeeeeeee:           5        5
```

The other command line:

```
'....' -ps -i 7rtf_3.pdb -gl Pocket_002_7rtf_3.pdb -o Pocket_002_7rtf_3_OUTPUT.txt
```

The `Pocket_002_2ert_A_OUTPUT.txt` file:

```
Input PDB-File:         7rtf_3.pdb
Pocket File:            Pocket_002_7rtf_3.pdb
eeeeee:                 405.0  
wwwwwwwwwwwww:          71.7    (17.7%)
rrrrrrrrrrrrr:          221.9   (54.8%)
tttttttttttttttt:       206.7   (51.0%)
yyyyyyyyyyyyyy:         84.4    (20.8%)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:     50.0    (1.5%)
BBBBBBBBBBBBB:          536.6  
cgdfeehhhhh:            458
tyrudioh:               78
serfgg:                 2        15
eeeeeeeeeeee:           5        5
```

The last command line:

```
'....' -ps -i 7rtf_3.pdb -gl Pocket_003_7rtf_3.pdb -o Pocket_003_7rtf_3_OUTPUT.txt
```

The `Pocket_003_2ert_A_OUTPUT.txt` file:

```
Input PDB-File:         7rtf_3.pdb
Pocket File:            Pocket_003_7rtf_3.pdb
eeeeee:                 405.0  
wwwwwwwwwwwww:          71.7    (17.7%)
rrrrrrrrrrrrr:          221.9   (54.8%)
tttttttttttttttt:       206.7   (51.0%)
yyyyyyyyyyyyyy:         84.4    (20.8%)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:     65.0    (75.7%)
BBBBBBBBBBBBB:          536.6  
cgdfeehhhhh:            458
tyrudioh:               78
serfgg:                 2        15
eeeeeeeeeeee:           5        5
```

At the end the file `ALL_SUMMAY.txt` should be like this:

```
Pocket_001_2ert_A.pdb     92.0    (22.7%)
Pocket_001_7rtf_3.pdb     80.0   (10.7%)
Pocket_002_7rtf_3.pdb     50.0    (1.5%)
Pocket_003_7rtf_3.pdb     65.0    (75.7%)
```

I need all `Pocket_nnn_XXXX_X_OUTPUT.txt` saved in the directory of work (`XXXX_X`). The file `ALL_SUMMARY.txt` could be saved in this directory `home/Desktop/Work/`.

Comment: Split your task in smaller chunks. Probably to each chunk there are questions here.

Comment: @TommasoPalomba It seems to me that you want to loop for each `*.pdb` file that you find in a certain directory, and inside the loop you want to DoSomething. You could start by checking the Guide that @pLumo posted above and see how you might write that.  Then it seems to me that what you want to do for each file is look in a related directory (changing `xxxx_X.pdb` to `xxxx.X`) and loop for each file that you find in there, and inside the loop you DoSomethingElse.

Comment: The "Something" that you want to do appears to be to run a command, passing the filename from the outside loop and the filename from the inside loop, then process the output and append to another file. Does this help to understand the suggestion to break your task down into smaller chunks? This is not the only way to do it, but it is generally called Top Down Design (you might like to do a websearch, as I find it very useful in programming).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Show an example of e.g. 2 or 3 pairs of files including the directory path where the files are located and tell where the corresponding output file(s) should be created. This will make your question more clear. Do you want to keep the resulting `output.txt` files for all pairs of input files or do you only need the extracted information in `SUMMARY_ALL.txt`?

Comment: @Bodo I've answer to your questions... I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your spec - which is not too clear not consistent - correctly, you need two loops to

a) find the primary .pdb files, and

b) the related pocket files.

After having created (and overwritten older versions of) the `output.txt` file, use `awk` to extract the desired fields into the result file. After having `cd` ed int the `ALL` dir, try

```
for FN1 in *.pdb                                                                # loop across all .pdb files
  do    PN="${FN1##*/}"
        PN="${PN%.pdb}"                                                         # construct subdir name
        for FN2 in "${PN/_/.}"/*.pdb                                            # 2nd loop across .pdb files in subdir
          do    "....." -ps -i "$FN1" -gl "$FN2" -o output.txt                  # create output.txt in parent dir
                awk -F: 'FNR == 2  ||                                           # extract desired fields
                         /^AAAAA/  ||
                         /^BBBBB/       {sub (/^ */, "", $2)
                                         printf "%20s%s", $2, /^BBBB/?"\n":""
                                        }
                        ' output.txt >> SUMMARY_ALL.txt                         # and append to result file
          done
  done
```

Cosmetic corrections to the result file (like printing header, line formatting) are left to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

The idea how to solve this problem is

- `cd` to the base directory `home/Desktop/Work`
- loop over all directories `????_?` (loop variable `dir`)

  - if there is a matching file `$dir.pdb`

    - `cd` into the directory `$dir`
    - loop over all `Pocket_*_$dir.pdb`

      - run the command to process the data and to create the corresponding output file
      - if successful extract the data from the output file to stdout
    - if necessary `cd` back to the parent directory
- put the output of this loop (i.e. all extracted data) into `ALL_SUMMARY.txt`

```
cd home/Desktop/Work
# edit: remove old summary file because now the script will append to it
rm SUMMARY_ALL.txt
for dir in ????_?
do
    if [ -f "$dir/$dir.pdb" ]
    then
        cd "$dir"
        for pocket in Pocket_*_"$dir.pdb"
        do
            out="${pocket%.pdb}_OUTPUT.txt"
            # edit: if the command '....' prints output this will end up in the summary file
            # '....' -ps -i "$dir.pdb" -gl "$pocket" -o "$out" && awk '/Pocket File:/ {pocket=$NF} /AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:/ {aaa1=$(NF-1);aaa2=$NF} /BBBBBBBBBBBBB:/ {bbb=$NF} END {print pocket,aaa1,aaa2,bbb}' "$out"
            '....' -ps -i "$dir.pdb" -gl "$pocket" -o "$out" && awk '/Pocket File:/ {pocket=$NF} /AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:/ {aaa1=$(NF-1);aaa2=$NF} /BBBBBBBBBBBBB:/ {bbb=$NF} END {print pocket,aaa1,aaa2,bbb}' "$out" >> ../SUMMARY_ALL.txt
        done
        cd ..
    fi
# edit: avoid putting other output into summanry file
# done > SUMMARY_ALL.txt
done
```

**Notes:**

The code is untested.

I assume that your command to generate the output file exits with status 0 on success and !=0 on error in order to use `&&` between this command and the `awk` command to extract the data.

The `awk` command is suitable to process a single file only. (It is used this way here.) If you want to process all output files in one run the script would need to be changed.

Comment: The first part of the script works well and for this I thank you very much. The creation phase of the SUMMARY file is wrong .. inside the file there are a lot of information related to the calculation it is doing but not the extracted lines that I want, I don't understand why

Comment: @TommasoPalomba What output does the command to create the output file print? I will change the script to avoid this problem.

Comment: If the summary file does not contain what you want, run the `awk` command for a single output file, e.g. `cd 7rtf_3; awk '/Pocket File:/ {pocket=$NF} /AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:/ {aaa1=$(NF-1);aaa2=$NF} /BBBBBBBBBBBBB:/ {bbb=$NF} END {print pocket,aaa1,aaa2,bbb}' Pocket_003_7rtf_3_OUTPUT.txt`

Comment: No it doesn't work. Can I use two separate scripts? The first one to calculate all the single files (and I use the one you recommended), each one in its own directory XXXX_X and the second script to copy of each single XXXX_X_output file only the line related to AAAAAAA in a SUMMARY_ALL.txt file?